# How to get class input value using jquery, inputs are coming from controller

Tags: php, html, jquery

In the example below, in controller, inputs fields are dynamically coming from server and render into view page through ajax

```php
public function Testing() {
    $query =.....;
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $i=1;

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<div class = "readingparent">
            <div class="form-group">'.$row['cm_name'].'</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control prev-'.$i.'" placeholder="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control present-'.$i.'" placeholder="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control reading" id="reading-'.$i.'" placeholder="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">   
            </div>
        </div>';

        $i++;
    }
}
```

These inputs are rendered into view page using ajax `$('.testingnew').html(data);`.
Problem is that I didn't get the second input value after the first input keyup.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
        $(document).on('keyup','.prev-'+i,function( e ) {
            var prev = $(this).val();
            // alert(prev);
            var present = $('.present-'+i).val();
            // var present = $(document).val($('.present-'+i).val());
            // var present = $(document).on("trigger", '.present-'+i).val();
            // var present = document.getElementsByClassName( '.present-'+i ).value;
            // var present = $(document).on('trigger','.present-'+i).val();
            // var present = $(document).on('change','.present-'+i).val();
            alert(present);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: That’s a weird way of using event delegation … These elements should rather have _one_ common class, and there should be _one_ keyup handler watching for the event happening on elements with that class added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code runs without error, the problem is from your handlers, it's called closure:

```
function( e ) { 
  ...
  var present = $('.present-'+i).val();
  alert(present);
}
```

All your handlers will keep and use the same reference of `i`, at the time a handler runs, it lookup to its lexical scope and use the reference `i = 4`. So the value of `'.present-'+i` will always be `.present-4`, and it makes you think the code won't run.

This can be fixed easily by using a smaller block scope:

````js
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
  const j = i;
  // use the reference of `j` instead of `i`
  $(document).on('keyup','.prev-'+ j,function( e ) {
    var present = $('.present-'+ j).val();
    alert(present);
  }
}```
````